# UIButton Changes Variable When Tapped?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have multiple `UIButton`s - `redButton`, `greenButton`, `yellowButton`, etc.  When you tap one of these buttons, another `UIImageView` will change its image accordingly to, say, `redImage`, `greenImage`, `yellowImage`.

How would I implement this?  I've tried this:

```
[self.redButton addTarget:self action:@selector(changeColour:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.greenButton addTarget:self action:@selector(changeColour:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.yellowButton addTarget:self action:@selector(changeColour:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And in `changeColour`:

```
-(void)changeColour:(id)sender{
  // How do I know which button was pressed?
}
```

All I'd like to know is which button was pressed.  Preferrably, I would like it so when a button is tapped, it changes an `int` variable called `colour`.  So, something like:

if `greenButton` was tapped, change `int = 1`.  If `redButton` was tapped, change `int = 2`.

I've searched StackOverflow and Google and the results say to include a method in the `@selector` of `action:`.  So what would I have to put in `changeColour` to recognise which button called `changeColour`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(void)changeColour:(id)sender
{
    if (sender == self.redButton) {
        // redButton action
    } else if (sender == self.greenButton) {
        // greenButton action
    } else if (sender == self.yellowButton) {
        // yellowButton action
    }
}
```

to do these kinds of identification the `sender` attribute was introduced.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tag property of UIView.
i.e.

```
self.redButton.tag = 1;
self.yellowButton.tag = 2;
```

In the chnageColor method, you can retrieve the same.

```
-(void)changeColour:(id)sender
{
  // How do I know which button was pressed?
  UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
  if(btn.tag == 1)
  //Red is pressed..
  //and you can check for other tags...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tap on the `UIButton` in the Interface Builder, and change the `tag` property of it in `Attributes Inspector`. Then access this `tag` property programmatically in your view controller to get to know which button was pressed.

Comment: Apple doc **Concepts in Objective-C Programming** reads, "If there are other ways to obtain a reference to an object [aside from IBOutlet], such as finding it through ... use of a tag (an assigned numeric identifier), you should do that instead." Why would they say this?

Comment: why would you need a tag when you have already a ivar/property to check against? you are just raising the need to maintenance and documentation. tags where meant to easily identify single subviews in huge hierarchies. In 5 years of professional iOS development I didn't use a tag once.